# How to refactor React mousemove Class to functional Component?

Tags: reactjs, refactoring, react-functional-component, react-class-based-component

I have a button which closes a navigation. This button follows the mouse. Everything is working, but I have a depricationwarning, which I wanna get rid of, but don't know exactly how. (I only know that useEffect is playing a certain role:

Here is the class:

```
import React from "react"

class NavigationCloseMouseButton extends React.Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    visible: true,
    offsetX: 0,
    offsetY: 0,
  }

  state = {
    xPosition: 0,
    yPosition: 0,
    mouseMoved: false,
    listenerActive: false,
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.addListener()
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.updateListener()
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.removeListener()
  }

  getTooltipPosition = ({ clientX: xPosition, clientY: yPosition }) => {
    this.setState({
      xPosition,
      yPosition,
      mouseMoved: true,
    })
  }

  addListener = () => {
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", this.getTooltipPosition)
    this.setState({ listenerActive: true })
  }

  removeListener = () => {
    window.removeEventListener("mousemove", this.getTooltipPosition)
    this.setState({ listenerActive: false })
  }

  updateListener = () => {
    if (!this.state.listenerActive && this.props.visible) {
      this.addListener()
    }

    if (this.state.listenerActive && !this.props.visible) {
      this.removeListener()
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        onClick={this.props.toggleNavigation}
        className="tooltip color-bg"
        style={{
          display:
            this.props.visible && this.state.mouseMoved ? "block" : "none",
          opacity: this.props.visible && this.state.mouseMoved ? "1" : "0",
          top: this.state.yPosition + this.props.offsetY,
          left: this.state.xPosition + this.props.offsetX,
        }}
      >
        Close Menu
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default NavigationCloseMouseButton
```

And this is what I've so far, but results with errors:
`ReferenceError: getTooltipPosition is not defined`

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"

const NavigationCloseMouseButton = () => {
  const defaults = {
    visible: true,
    offsetX: 0,
    offsetY: 0,
  }

  const defaultState = {
    xPosition: 0,
    yPosition: 0,
    mouseMoved: false,
    listenerActive: false,
  }

  const [defaultProps, setDefaultProps] = useState(defaults)
  const [state, setState] = useState(defaultState)

  useEffect(() => {
    // Update the document title using the browser API
    addListener()
  }, [])

  getTooltipPosition = ({ clientX: xPosition, clientY: yPosition }) => {
    setState({
      xPosition,
      yPosition,
      mouseMoved: true,
    })
  }

  addListener = () => {
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", getTooltipPosition)
    setState({ listenerActive: true })
  }

  removeListener = () => {
    window.removeEventListener("mousemove", getTooltipPosition)
    setState({ listenerActive: false })
  }

  updateListener = () => {
    if (!state.listenerActive && props.visible) {
      addListener()
    }

    if (state.listenerActive && !props.visible) {
      removeListener()
    }
  }

  return (
    <div
      onClick={props.toggleNavigation}
      className="tooltip color-bg"
      style={{
        display: props.visible && state.mouseMoved ? "block" : "none",
        opacity: props.visible && state.mouseMoved ? "1" : "0",
        top: state.yPosition + props.offsetY,
        left: state.xPosition + props.offsetX,
      }}
    >
      Close Menu
    </div>
  )
}

export default NavigationCloseMouseButton
```

Comment: Well...where did you declare `getTooltipPosition`? I see only an assignment. That's true also for the other functions. Note that with `useEffect({}, [])` you can return a function to perform what you did in `componentWillUnmount()`. Also: what `defaultProps` is for? Definitely they won't be seen as defaults for component's properties. Final note: when you call `setState({ x: y })` then you replace the ENTIRE previous value, it does not behave like `Component.setState()` where what you provide is automatically merged with the existing state.

Answer (score 0):

#### Setting Defaults

You can destructure individual props from the props object (the argument of the function component).  While destructuring, you can use the `=` operator to set a default value for when this prop is not set.

```
const NavigationCloseMouseButton = ({ visible = true, offsetX = 0, offsetY = 0, toggleNavigation }) => {
```

#### Updating a Listener

I'm sure there a lots of great answers about this so I won't go into too much detail.

You want to handle adding and removing the listener from inside your `useEffect`.  You should use a `useEffect` cleanup function for the final remove.  We don't want to be adding and removing the same listener so we can memoize it with `useCallback`.

I'm not sure what you are trying to do with `listenerActive`.  This could be a prop, but it also seems a bit redundant with `visible`.  I don't know that we need this at all.

#### Calculating Offset

I also don't know that it makes sense to pass `offsetX` and `offsetY` as props.  We need the mouse to be on top of the tooltip in order for it to be clickable.  We can measure the tooltip `div` inside this component and deal with it that way.

```
// ref to DOM node for measuring
const divRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

// can caluculate offset instead of passing in props
const offsetX = -.5 * (divRef.current?.offsetWidth || 0);
const offsetY = -.5 * (divRef.current?.offsetHeight || 0);
```

#### Animation

Setting the style property `display` as `"block"` or `"none"` makes it hard to do any sort of CSS transition.  Instead, I recommend that you handle style switching by changing the `className`.  You could still set `display: block` and `display: none` on those classes, but I am choosing to use `transform: scale(0);` instead.

#### Code

```
const NavigationCloseMouseButton = ({
  visible = true,
  toggleNavigation
}) => {

  // state of the movement
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    xPosition: 0,
    yPosition: 0,
    mouseMoved: false
  });

  // memoized event listener
  const getTooltipPosition = useCallback(
    // plain event, not a React synthetic event
    ({ clientX: xPosition, clientY: yPosition }) => {
      setState({
        xPosition,
        yPosition,
        mouseMoved: true
      });
    },
    []
  ); // never re-creates

  useEffect(() => {
    // don't need to listen when it's not visible
    if (visible) {
      window.addEventListener("mousemove", getTooltipPosition);
    } else {
      window.removeEventListener("mousemove", getTooltipPosition);
    }

    // clean-up function to remove on unmount
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("mousemove", getTooltipPosition);
    };
  }, [visible, getTooltipPosition]); // re-run the effect if prop `visible` changes

  // ref to DOM node for measuring
  const divRef = useRef(null);

  // can caluculate offset instead of passing in props
  const offsetX = -.5 * (divRef.current?.offsetWidth || 0);
  const offsetY = -.5 * (divRef.current?.offsetHeight || 0);

  // don't show until after mouse is moved
  const isVisible = visible && state.mouseMoved;

  return (
    <div
      ref={divRef}
      onClick={toggleNavigation}
      // control most styling through className
      className={`tooltip ${isVisible ? "tooltip-visible" : "tooltip-hidden"}`}
      style={{
        // need absolute position to use top and left
        position: "absolute",
        top: state.yPosition + offsetY,
        left: state.xPosition + offsetX
      }}
    >
      Close Menu
    </div>
  );
};
```

#### Other Uses

We can easily make this `NavigationCloseMouseButton` into a more flexible `MovingTooltip` by removing some of the hard-coded specifics.

- Get the contents from `props.children` instead of always using "Close Menu"
- Accept a `className` as a prop
- Change the name of `toggleNavigation` to `onClick`

[Code Sandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/moving-tooltip-mo72f?file=/src/index.tsx)